# Upgrading TFS 2010 RC to TFS 2010

Tags: installation, team-foundation-server

I ran the RTM version of TFS2010 on my server that has TFS 2010 RC on it and it gave me this error message.

[alt text http://xs.to/image-766A_4BCE01EC.jpg](http://xs.to/image-766A_4BCE01EC.jpg)

I thought you could upgrade from the RC to the final version.  Was I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are correct. You have to uninstall RC first, then re-install the RTM. At some point during install you can point to your database and the install process will pick that up.

Answer (score 1):

Might also be worth checking out [Bryan Krieger's blog post about upgrading](http://bit.ly/bFwXmn)